# Trigger goal on dynamic item binding

Tags: goals

I have list of items which also contains button. I am binding that list via `Json` . Now I want to trigger `goal` when some user click on that button.

- I cannot apply goal on page because I want to trigger goal on button click
- I tried to use `sc_trk` but because on click it is redirecting to some other domain, then it is also not working.
- I tried to call web api on button click but when I am fetching goal item from DB using `GetItem` method, it is returning null.

Below is my code :

```
public static bool TriggerGoal(Sitecore.Data.ID goalId)
        {
            if (!Tracker.IsActive)
            {
                Tracker.StartTracking();
            }

            if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null)
            {
                Sitecore.Data.Items.Item goalItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goalId); // Getting null value
                if (goalItem != null)
                {
                    var goalTrigger = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[goalItem.ID.ToGuid()];
                    var goalEventData = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal(goalTrigger);
                    goalEventData.Data = goalItem["Name"];
                    goalEventData.ItemId = goalItem.ID.ToGuid();
                    goalEventData.DataKey = goalItem.Paths.Path;
                    goalEventData.Text = "Goal for Logic";
                    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] UrlModel model)
        {
TriggerGoal(someguid);
}
```

Can any one suggest me better approach?

Comment: The web API method is one which you can use to with javascript for this...OOTB it does not support for the button click. I guess if you can share your code for the web API, we can check why you are getting null for goal item.

Comment: What is the Sitecore version you are using?

Comment: I am using Sitecore 9.0.2

Comment: Can you try to use the following to trigger the goal upon the button click: `var goalDefinition = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[goalId];

Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal(goalDefinition);`

Comment: I have  added code

Comment: I don't know how you are calling but may be your web API is out from the Sitecore Context, try by getting database first- 
var webDb = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("web"); Sitecore.Data.Items.Item goalItem = webDb.GetItem(goalId);

Comment: @Mahendra I tried that as well but no success

Comment: hmmm....same for master database?

Comment: I tried for both master and web

Answer (score 3):

### Sitecore 9.x

When you call the API, you must remember to include security so that the cookies go with the request. Mainly the analytics cookie.

In the code below the `GetPageForApi()`, if requested, will get the page before the Api call. This is since the API is a page request. Without using previous page, the goal would be on the API call itself.

#### The Api

```
[HttpGet]
[SkipAnalyticsTrackingApi]
public ActionResult TriggerIAmWithoutEmailGoal()
{
    var response = new BaseResponseDTO<TriggerGoalResponseModel>();
    try
    {
        this.eventRepository.TriggerGoalOnce(PageContent.Constants.Goals.IamWithoutEmail, true);

        response.Data = new TriggerGoalResponseModel()
        {
            Result = true,
        };

        return new JsonNet(response);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        // log your error

        response.Error = ex.Message;
        return new JsonNet(response);
    }
}
```

#### The attribute

```
public class SkipAnalyticsTrackingApiAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Tracker.Current?.CurrentPage?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

#### The repo

```
private readonly IDefinitionManager<IGoalDefinition> goalDefinitionManager;

// The goalDefinitionManager is injected by DI
public EventRepository(IDefinitionManager<IGoalDefinition> goalDefinitionManager)
{
    this.goalDefinitionManager = goalDefinitionManager;
}

public void TriggerGoal(ID goalId, bool fromApi = false, int engagementValue = 0)
{
    var goalDefinition = this.goalDefinitionManager.Get(goalId.Guid, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (goalDefinition == null)
    {
        Log.Warn($"Cannot find goal: {goalId}", this);
        return;
    }

    Log.Info($"Goal Triggered: Contact: {Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId} : {goalId}", this);

    var page = fromApi ? GetPageForApi() : Tracker.Current.CurrentPage;

    page.RegisterGoal(goalDefinition);
}

public void TriggerGoalOnce(ID goalId,bool fromApi = false)
{
    if (IfGoalAlreadyExists(goalId)) return;

    TriggerGoal(goalId, fromApi);
}

public bool IfGoalAlreadyExists(ID goalId)
{
    if (Tracker.Current?.Session == null) return false;

    var goalsTriggered = Tracker.Current?.Session?.Interaction?.Pages?.SelectMany(x => x.PageEvents).Where(x => x.IsGoal).ToList();

    var behaviorCache = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact.KeyBehaviorCache.Goals.Any(x => x.Id == goalId.ToGuid());
    var pages = goalsTriggered?.Any(x => x.PageEventDefinitionId == goalId.ToGuid()) ?? false;

    return behaviorCache || pages;
}

private IPageContext GetPageForApi()
{
    if (Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.PreviousPage == null)
        return Tracker.Current.CurrentPage;

    return Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.PreviousPage;
}
```

### Sitecore 8.2

The API and Attribute are the same as above. But the way to trigger the goal is on the tracker in 8.2.

#### The repo

```
public void TriggerGoal(ID goalPath, bool fromApi = false)
{
    if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current?.CurrentPage != null)
    {
        // Trigger a goal
        var goalItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goalPath); // Goal item

        if (goalItem != null)
        {
            var goal = new PageEventItem(goalItem); // Wrapper for goal
            var page = fromApi ? Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.PreviousPage : Tracker.Current.CurrentPage;

            if (page == null)
            {
                errorService.LogError(new Exception($"Page is null. Cannnot fire goal. Goal ID {goalPath.Guid}, fromApi = {fromApi}"), this);
                return;
            }


            var pageEventsRow = page.Register(goal); // Goal rtecord to be stored
            pageEventsRow.Data = goalItem["Description"];
            Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications();
            Log.Info($"Goal Triggered: Contact: {Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId} : {goalPath} / {goalItem.Name}", this);
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void TriggerGoalOnce(ID goalId, bool fromApi)
{
    if (IfGoalAlreadyExists(goalId)) return;

    TriggerGoal(goalId, fromApi);
}

public bool IfGoalAlreadyExists(ID goalId)
{
    var goalsTriggered = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.SelectMany(x => x.PageEvents).Where(x => x.IsGoal).ToList();
    return goalsTriggered.Any(x => x.PageEventDefinitionId == goalId.ToGuid());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. My problem is that I am getting item when I am passing Home page id then it is returning me item, but when I am passing GoalID then it is giving me null value